# IE7 Floating Radio Button Problem

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am having problem in IE7 for regristration form I made for this site, and it only messes up on the bottom and only occurs in IE7. The page with the problem is this one:

https://www.iptlock.com/createaccount.php

The radio buttons on the bottom of this page appear in reverse order. I have them set up in CSS like this but this is not how they are displayed. Any ideas why?

```
    #packagechoice{
        width:20px;
        position:relative;
        margin-left:190px;
        margin-top:15px;
        float:left;
    }

    #packagechoice2{
        width:20px;
        position:relative;
        margin-left:190px;
        margin-top:15px;
        float:left;
    }
    #packagechoice3{
        width:20px;
        position:relative;
        margin-top:15px;
        float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `float:left` the leftmost item needs to appear first in your HTML. Your HTML is in reverse order.

**EDIT:**

The problem with your HTML is that the radio buttons and the packages are separate line-items. They appear distant in the HTML. Your code also suffers from DIV-itis. It lacks semantic structure which is why things aren't cooperating the way you expect.

Consider this:

```
<style>
.packages ul, .packages li {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.packages li {
   float:left;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
</style>

<div class='packages'>
    <ul>
        <li>
             --- your package ---
             --- your radio button ---
        <li>
        <li>
             --- your package ---
             --- your radio button ---
        <li>
        <li>
             --- your package ---
             --- your radio button ---
        <li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Things that go together are LISTS. There is already a list tag in HTML: `UL` or `OL`, using it properly is important and is an excellent way to eliminate DIV-itis. Lists make semantic sense and are friendlier for search bots and screen readers.

There is an excellent article on [taming lists](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/).

Understanding how to use lists effectively is the difference between someone who is a hack and someone who is a pro. GO LEARN THIS.

Comment: Tried that, its still the same.